# why need to build boost to make a downloaded project working?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

IDE is VS2012

I am new to c++ and trying to get a opensource project work which references some boost libs.
Just following some "Get Started" step by step guides, my question is do i have to run the bootstrap.bat and bjam.exe to build boost? would it work if I just add boost path to the projcet include path to make the ide can find the referenced files? if so what's the benefit to build boost in advance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modifying the include path is not enough if the project uses a library that needs compiling. The reason is that the compiler just sees the include directive for the header file; it cannot guess (and it's pretty much impossible to guess) what other .cpp files it would need to compile in order to get everything you need.

You could in theory grab the Boost source files and reference them from your project explicitly, but that means you also need to keep track of what their dependencies are and grab those too.

Boost, like all larger projects, has a build system where those dependencies are already taken care of. In theory, you should be able to reference the build system project from your own and say, "Use this." However, the extreme diversity in C++ build systems means that this is generally not possible; you can't reference a Boost.Build project from Visual Studio, or a SCons project from CMake, or anything like it.

So in general, your best choice is to build a project using its own supplied build system, then take the result of that build (in Boost's case, a directory full of .lib and .dll files) and reference that from your project.

Comment: thanks @SebastianRedl, understand. if compiler can only see headers, then how compiler know which lib/dll have the resources for that h file?

Comment: because you tell it through the command line or project settings

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Some boost libraries are header only which don't have to be compiled.  Others are not and have to be compiled in order to use.

Comment: He's asking why he can't simply compile them when he compiles the code base vs installing separately